# How to prevent user from selecting the same value from more than one combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a simple class as such:

```
public class Item
{
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I have a List of this class in my Mainwindow.xaml.cs as such:

```
public List<Item> AllItems=GetAllItems();
```

I have four properties of Item class in my Mainwindow.xaml.cs as such:

```
public Item Item1{get;set;}
public Item Item2{get;set;}
public Item Item3{get;set;}
public Item Item4{get;set;}
```

This List:AllItems is databinded to four Comboboxes as under:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Item1.ID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode2" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"  DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Item1.ID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode3" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Item1.ID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode4" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Item1.ID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I have four TextBoxes corresponding to these four Comboboxes as such:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtName1" Text="{Binding Item1.Name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtName2" Text="{Binding Item2.Name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtName3" Text="{Binding Item3.Name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtName4" Text="{Binding Item4.Name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What i want is that the user should never be able to select the same ID from more than one combobox.
Is there some simple way that could be done,especially using xaml only?How can i hide or show the items selected/unselected from other comboboxes so that the user can't select the same ID from more than one combobox ever?
So far i have tried to send the selected Item and the entire List to a MultivalueConverter and eliminating/adding items to the Lists there itself,but this seems too meesy.Any other better idea would be appreciated.

Comment: XAML is a *markup* language...it is not meant to be used to implement this kind of logic. You should use a programming language to do this.

Comment: @mm8:with my limited understanding of WPF so far,i am currently employing Multivalue converters where i am sending not one but all four Lists upon change of each SelectedItem and am doing all the plus-minus to the lists there..tx for the update there.atleast now i won't spend wondering whether it might be possible in XAML and i wasn't knowing..:-)..

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate list for each of your ComboBoxes. You could then add a [LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler to each of them. You could use this to repopulate the lists for the other ComboBoxes to exclude the selection.

For example, if I've got 5 items in my list; initially I'll be able to select all 5 in any of my ComboBoxes. When I select Item1 in ComboBox1 the LostFocus event handler will update the lists behind ComboBoxes 2-4 to remove Item1. When I then select Item2 in ComboBox2 the LostFocus event handler will then update the lists behind ComboBoxes 3 and 4 to remove Item2. And so on...

An alternative approach might be to let the user select whatever they like and then run some kind of validation on the selected values to make sure that they're unique. This [article](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) goes through some of your options.

Personally, I'd go with the second approach; perhaps with a message above the textboxes indicating that the selection must be unique. You could indicate any errors and block any actions that rely on the selection while it's invalid but you're not having to update your data constantly which will probably lead to a smoother UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code to hide the selected item in different combobox

```
 for (int count = 0; count <= cmb1.Items.Count -1; count++)
    {

    if((ComboBoxItem)(cmb1.Items[count])).SelectedValue==TextBox1.Text)
 ((ComboBoxItem)(cmb1.Items[count])).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

This code you can write in selected event of the comboxes.

I guess you can write the same logic using triggers in XAML

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this kind of logic in your view models. Here is an example for you that should give you the idea:

**View Model:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        AllItems = new List<Item>() { new Item { Name = "1" }, new Item { Name = "2" }, new Item { Name = "3" }, new Item { Name = "4" } };
    }

    public List<Item> AllItems { get; set; }

    private Item _item1;
    public Item Item1
    {
        get { return _item1; }
        set
        {
            _item1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            if (value != null)
                value.CanSelect = false;
        }
    }

    private Item _item2;
    public Item Item2
    {
        get { return _item2; }
        set
        {
            _item2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            if (value != null)
                value.CanSelect = false;
        }
    }

    private Item _item3;
    public Item Item3
    {
        get { return _item3; }
        set
        {
            _item3 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();
            if (value != null)
                value.CanSelect = false;
        }
    }

    private Item _item4;
    public Item Item4
    {
        get { return _item4; }
        set
        {
            _item4 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            if (value != null)
                value.CanSelect = false;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _canSelect = true;
    public bool CanSelect
    {
        get { return _canSelect; }
        set { _canSelect = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Style x:Key="icstyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding CanSelect}" />
</Style>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item1}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource icstyle}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode2" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item2}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource icstyle}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode3" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item3}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource icstyle}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCode4" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item4}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource icstyle}"/>
```